# Recursively calls onBindViewHolder from spinner Item SelectListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I have a spinner in my recycler view, when I select any value in spinner I have to reload the recyclerView by calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` method, the thing is when ever `onBindViewHolder` called, the spinner `onItemSelected()` method also calls autmatically , is there any way to block this ? its a kind of recursion happens now.

**My code**

```
  holder.mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long
                        id) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    myModel.setSelected(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: can u give whole adapter code?

Comment: I dont think that will help you to resolve, there is no issue in adapter, the issue is whenever we set setOnItemSelectedListener to  spinner, it will call methods automatically.

Comment: No it doesn't call automatically, it will only be called when an item of spinner is selected.

Comment: did you find any answer?

Comment: i have same problem. have you found any solution

Comment: Yes you have reset its click listener just before setting it as selected and have to set the listener after again. Thats the workaround for this issue